# HAProxy Rate limiting per IP with queuing

Tags: haproxy, rate-limiting

I'm moving towards HA using it to replace also NGINX and I've a question regarding how to do a Rate Limiting in HA that enables queuing the request instead of closing them.

I was able to limit per IP following those examples: https://www.haproxy.com/blog/four-examples-of-haproxy-rate-limiting/ . However, when the limit is reached, the users see the error and connection is closed.

Since I come from NGINX, it has this handy feature https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/ where connection that exceed the threshold can be closed, but in general they are queued. Thus the user will still be able to do the calls but delayed without him getting errors and keep the overall number of requests within threshold.

Is there anything similar in HA? It should limit/queueing the user by IP.

To explain with an example, we have two users `Alice`, with ip `A.A.A.A` and `Bob` with ip `B.B.B.B`
The threshold is `30r/minute`.

So in 1 minute:

- Alice does 20 requests. -> that's fine
- Bob does 60 requests. -> the system caps the requset to 30 and then process the other 30 later on (maybe also adding timeout/delay)
- Alice does 50 request -> the first 40 are fine, the next 10 are queued.
- Bob does 20 requests -> they are queue after the one above.

is this possible?

Comment: What is the haproxy configuration? Especially timeout queue and per client tables.  To maintain good response time, typically queued is only for "a few" seconds.

Comment: Sorry, i did not gate much out of this. can you please provide some info regarding how to do that? in nginx it's very easy to set, while in HA it seems that doing that per client is very difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that i found is rather complex and includes a lua script. But it works!

i created a gist here to simplify sharing. it has a docker-compose to create the env and needed config. https://gist.github.com/esseti/1382f7df039f9098b425f2a7a338a749

and then, using `AB` you run `ab -n 500  -A A:B http://localhost:8888/`

NOTE: i wrote this while ago and then it has been modified by other people. It should work, but probably requires refinement for your specific cases. especially the HA configuration.